# Google Analytics showing active usage for down site

Tags: google-analytics, github-pages

I have a little domain I have been toying with for a year.  I put it up on GitHub Pages and I believe I configured Google Analytics.  There was no real content there, surely no visitors, and the site went down for unknown reasons at an unknown time.  We do use email on this domain, hosted by Google Apps; this has been up and used continuously.

Now, while resurrecting the site and trying to configure Google Analytics, I logged into Google Analytics and I see months of history.  Usage is small but very diverse with hundreds of sessions logged from all over the world, over the past year.

I cannot fathom what produced these data (believing the site to be down for this period, and it never having content anyway), and I am concerned to start using this analytics token out of concern it will continue to report spurious data.

How can I determine the source of these data?  How can I zero out the account and get it report true zero usage before I start using it again?

Ryan

Comment: Sounds like bots and crawlers. Either from search engines or otherwise. There are a few bots that crawl github and gh-pages looking for amazon keys. ect.

Answer (score 1):

There could be someone using your UA-CODE or maybe even you accidently still using that code on another page, luckily, creating a new code is a breeze so you should consider creating a new code for your next project